# Graphic Design brochure

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, resize, page-layout, creative-cloud

I want to design a brochure-like the image and I don't know what size I will use in adobe InDesign ??[image]

Comment: Welcome aysaa! How is anyone here to know what size you should use?

Comment: I but the image of the size I wanted?

Comment: There's *no way* to determine the size of that brochure from the image. It could be 2x3" folded.. or 4x6" folded... or 9x12" folded... or 6x8" folded.. there's just no way to tell.

Comment: see this the link for it https://creativemarket.com/pmvchamara/4657765-A4-Four-Fold-Brochure-Mockups

Comment: she said the size is a5 so if I use 11*8.5 cm size is good

Comment: You could merely *purchase* that template.

Comment: I own this template but don't know the size of the file to open in InDesign ..i Hope you understand!

Comment: Sorry, I really don't. If you have the template it *should* open in Indesign at the size it was designed for.

Comment: she is a PSD mockup template can I take the size from it!

Comment: An image is sizeless as long as yoir aspect ratio is the same its a mocup of the same thing.

Comment: If you have the template and see its dimensions, you have *considerably* more information than anyone here has.

Answer (score 1):

**If** the folded size is to be A5, then the image is depicting four A5 items side-by-side. The height for the document would be one (A5 height) by four (A5 widths).

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if you are doing this for a school project, or to make a mockup only...

But that is not the way things are done in real life.

In real life, you need to find out if the project can actually be printed.

Does the paper exist on the dimensions you want? Does a printer can actually print the dimensions, is it feasible to do that size without too much waste of paper?

---

If you are doing a mockup only, just take the dimensions the mockup has or says. If it does not have a proper size, just make a gess. Letter? A4? A5? Just make a decision.

---

If it is for real, go and find a commercial printer, find out the dimensions they can actually print (print area) the paper size they can feed the machine, then you have the maximum dimensions. From there again, make some decisions on what is the best size for the project.

Buy some sheets of paper so you have a real physical dummy to feel the product, based on the characteristics of the paper, mainly weight, hardness and size.

Comment: Also, don't forget to compensate for the weight of the stock when folding. You might end up with a lip.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of looks like 4 times an A5, in which case your InDesign document will need to be 592mm (width) by 210mm (height).